# Sharepoint workflow deployment error basepackagepath

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow

I'm getting this error while deploying a workflow in sharepoint 2010

**Error occurred in deployment step 'Retract Solution': This required project property is not found or has a value of null or empty string: BasePackagePath**

Its building fine and I tried retract, it also succeeded.

I am using visual studio to deploy.

Can anyone tell me what has to be the value of the base path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem it was due to permission i had to use the far admin account to deploy it.

This is the error
"The "CompileWorkflowTask" task failed unexpectedly.
System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported."

So after some search i came up with this [link](http://microsoftdev.blogspot.com/2009/04/workflow-compilation-error.html)

But it got built but showed the error in my question

But the first one is the error.
And you need admin privileges to deploy it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the BasePackagePath in your .user file that is in the same directory as your SharePoint project file.

In my user file the following entries were missing. After adding these properties below the siteurl I could deploy the project. You can change this by using for instance notepad.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Project ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <SharePointSiteUrl>http://siteurl:9425/</SharePointSiteUrl>
        <ProjectView>ShowAllFiles</ProjectView>
        <BasePackagePath>bin\Debug</BasePackagePath>
        <LayoutPath>pkg\package</LayoutPath>
      </PropertyGroup>
```